# Resource exhaustion on web server - socket basic explanation

Tags: sockets, http, tcp

I connect to a web server supported by an embedded system with Internet Explorer 9. Windows 7 is on the client side.
The web page have many tabs and I browse across until the problem occurs. It takes about one minute to happen.
The embedded system  freezes so it not possible to browse and it does not respond to ping. After a moment the embedded system will recover because it is designed to reboot. I joined a Wireshark trace in which you can see 92 connections (use the filter "tcp.stream eq 0" with values [0,91]) and you will see. I have the source code so I know that the embedded system does not support more than 37 simultaneous connections. Is the cause an exhaustion of the resources?

But I have a more basic question and I really more appreciate an answer to it. The web server is at 172.21.1.12 port 80 and the client is at
 172.21.9.70 and variable port numbers (see the trace). Because the IP and port on the server side do not change, how many sockets are in use on the server side? The question is important because the more sockets are opened, the more probably there is an exhaustion of the resources.
 If the answer is only 1 socket then I must conclude there is no lack of resources because it can support 37.

I also suggest you use the filter ip.addr == 172.21.1.12 in Wireshark.

I thought I could upload the wireshark file. I dont know how to share it with you. Help please?
Dropbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the caveat that you haven't specified your embedded system, most TCP stacks will create a new socket for each new connection, and the mapping from socket to connection is 1-1.

When a packet arrives to the network stack, it has to associate that packet to the right socket. Usually, this is accomplished by employing a map from the TCP 4-tuple to the socket, where the 4-tuple consists of [local-ip, local-port, remote-ip, remote-port].

A server makes its service available by listening on a fixed local port that is known to clients wanting to use the service. As you understand, this is usually port 80 for a web server, and the software interface for most TCP implementations dedicate a socket for the purpose of allowing the API to perform operations on the network parameters for this service. However, the socket is not fully connected (the last two parts of the 4-tuple are set to a special "not specified" value, usually all bits 0). When a new connection is accepted, a new socket is created where the 4-tuple consists of the local information of the listening socket and the remote information taken from the source address and port of the SYN packet that initiated the TCP connection.

The limit on the number of connections a server can support is based on how the operating system is configured (you say yours limits it to 37). Using the 4-tuple, a single service (that is a fixed local-ip and local-port) will have an absolute limit of (2<sup>ADDR_BITS</sup> - RESERVED_ADDRS) × (2<sup>16</sup> - RESERVED_PORTS). For IPv4, the number of bits is 32, while for IPv6, the number of bits is 128.

When creating a connection, the client will specify the destination address and port (which fills out the remote information for the 4-tuple), but usually leave the source information unspecified. The TCP stack will choose an appropriate source address based on routing, and select an available source port (which will become the local information to complete the 4-tuple). In theory, any source port that is not being used by the selected local interface to communicate to the same remote service can be used as the local port. Most stacks will dedicate a set of the higher numbered ports for this purpose (referred to as the ephemeral port range).